# Finding tuples if it only exists in all occurrences of a constraint

Tags: relational-algebra

Database (all entries are integers):

```sql
ID | BUDGET
1  | 20
8  | 20
10 | 20
5  | 4
9  | 4
10 | 4
1  | 11
9  | 11
```

Suppose my constraint is having a budget of >= 10.
I would want to return ID of 1 only in this case. How do I go about it?
I've tried taking the cross product of itself after selecting budget >= 10 and returning if id1 = id2 and budget1 <> budget2 but that does not work in the case where there's only 1 budget that is >= 10. (EG below)

```sql
ID | BUDGET
1  | 20
8  | 20
10 | 20
1  | 4
5  | 4
9  | 4
10 | 4
9  | 4
```

If I were to do what I did for the first example, nothing will be returned as budget1 <> budget2 will result in an empty table.

EDIT1: I can only use relational algebra to solve the problem. So SQL's exist, where and count keywords cant be used.

Edit2: Only project, select, rename, set difference, set union, left join, right join, full inner join, natural joins, set intersection and cross product allowed

Comment: Really you can’t use the division? It is a very useful (and standard!) operator in Relational Algebra...

Comment: How would division be used in this case?

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34978533/2382734

Comment: So if A / B in relational algebra, any tuples from A that contains any rows from B will be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not completely clear to me. If you want to return all the ID for which there is a budget greater than 10, and no budget less than 10, the expression is simply the following:

```
π(ID)(σ(BUDGET>=10)(R)) - π(ID)(σ(BUDGET<10)(R))
```

If, an the other hand, you want all the ID which have *all the budgets present in the relation and greater then 10*, then we must use the `÷` operator:

```
R ÷ π(BUDGET)(σ(BUDGET>=10)(R))
```

From your comment, the second case is the correct one. Let’s see how to compute the division from its definition (applied to two generic relations R(A) and S(B)):

R ÷ S = π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) - π<sub>A-B</sub>((π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) x S) - R)

where R is the original relation, and

S = π(BUDGET)(σ(BUDGET>=10)(R)),

that is:

```
BUDGET
------
20
11
```

Starting from the inner expression:

π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) is equal to π<sub>ID</sub>(R) =

```
ID
--
1
5
8
9
10
```

then π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) x S) is:

```
ID BUDGET
---------
 1  20
 1  11
 5  20
 5  11
 8  20
 8  11
 9  20
 9  11
10  20
10  11
```

then ((π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) x S) - R) is:

```
ID BUDGET
---------
 5  20
 5  11
 8  11
 9  20
10  20
```

then π<sub>A-B</sub>((π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) x S) - R) is:

```
ID
__
 5
 8
 9
10
```

and, finally, subtracting this relation from π<sub>A-B</sub>(R) we obtain the result:

```
ID
--
 1
```

Comment: In this case the ID must exist in all budgets that are >=10. If we're using this π(ID)(σ(BUDGET>=10)(R)) - π(ID)(σ(BUDGET<10)(R)) it'll return 1 and 8 which is not correct as 8 is does not exist with a budget of 11

Comment: So, the operator to use is the division. I edited the answer.

Comment: Omg thank you!! It's was really tricky to wrap my head around the division thing but your original post helped a ton. Thank you!!